# CSS Style tag should not shown in DOM

Tags: angular, less

[image]

As you can see less file is rendering like this in DOM

I don't want that.

Is there any solution that i can hide Style tag to the end user?

https://blog.angularindepth.com/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client-d4adf15c4975

This blog also didn't helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `styles.css` file to write your css. It will hide your css.

As well as you can put your links of "css" or "less" in `styles` array in `angular-cli.json`.

For example,

**angular-cli.json**

```
"apps" : [
    ...
    ...
    "styles" : [
       "styles.css",
       "css/Styles.less"
    ]
]
```

Comment: As per right now in my project if I change whole less file to css .It will take too much time.So can you give me another solution regarding to hide less file style tags.

Comment: You can also put "less" files in `angular-cli.json`'s styles array.

Comment: Are you sure it will hide all style tags

Comment: there is no angular-cli.json file instead of that I have __dot__angular-cli.json file.

Comment: Yes thats same!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161089/discussion-between-aarsh-and-shreenil-patel).

Answer (score 0):

Use External CSS.
This will hide your CSS tags

Comment: I am using less and it is render as css in browser. I want to stop that